# How to add html contents taken from an html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script

```
$('table#preview td.price').each(function(){
var price = parseInt($(this).html());
var total;
if(price == ''){
price = 0;
}
total += price;
alert(total);
});
```

What it does is get the column that has the class price then supposedly adds it all up.

However, all I get from this code is NaN. I don't get what's wrong with the code.

Please note the script **if(price == '')**. I've done this because initially there are no contents in the table.

Edit: Here the html

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>pen</td>
    <td class="price>6</td>
    <td>paper</td>
    <td class="price>8</td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Could you give us a html example as wel please?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you're parsing it as an integer, do you even need to do the string comparison?

Comment: could you put price into an alert to see what you are adding?

Comment: $(this).html() is html not an integer. try converting var price to number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>Try using the `.text()` method instead of `.html()` method, it should hopefully help get rid of the NaN errors.</del> You'll want to declare the `total` outside the scope of each iteration so it doesn't get reset each time. Try giving this a go, I've simplified it slightly to also include a check against the number `price`:

```
var total = 0;
$('table#preview td.price').each(function()
{
    var price = parseInt($(this).text());
    if (!isNaN(price))
    {
        total += price;
    }
});

alert('The total is: ' + total);
```

### Update

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jAak/). N.B. `.html()` should also work.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked. I'll mark this as the correct answer in 5 minutes. The system wont let me do it now.

Comment: @Learner After checking, it appears that `.html()` works as well :)