# Sum total for column in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code isn't working. I need to sum all by column as you can see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/). What's going wrong?

#### HTML

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Watermelon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
        <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
        <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
        <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
        <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
        <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
        <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   $(".rowDataSd").each(function() {
      newSum.call(this);
    });

});


function newSum() {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table');
    var total = 0;

    $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)/)[1];

$table.find('tr:not(.totalColumn) .rowDataSd').each(function()  {
        total += parseInt($(this).html());

});

$table.find('.totalColumn td:nth-child('')').html(total);
}
```

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10702457/259656

Comment: Your JavaScript code has quite a few errors. All shown in the console. Please check your code yourself first, before asking here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a [jsffile](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/13/). hope this helps

```
  <table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">5</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
            <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
            <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
<script>
       var totals=[0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

            $dataRows.each(function() {
                $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                    totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
                $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: question upgraded: http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/15/ if i have multile column with different class name it become not working.

Comment: 2. how do i calculate the row total?

Comment: thats trivial. the each on your ".rowAA" will iterate from 0 to 2.

Comment: so you are uodating the totals[0] and totals[1]. the each on ".rowBB" will override the same values (totals[0],totals[1]). thats why you keep having 0 for others. thats a different situation. check this [fiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/22/)

Comment: how about the total by row and total overall? (either by row or column for total overall) http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/23/

Comment: for the overall total it the sum of the totals (rows or columns). iterate on the array and assign it to the column html.

Comment: @Aymen hey this is cool code !I m using it but found out it do  not calculate values with dot like 11.98 :( any advice ?

Comment: I have been looking for an answer to this, but I cant find 1 single person that explain his code........

Answer (score 9):

### [jsFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/11/)

To achieve this, we can take full advantage of the `thead` and `tfoot` tags within the `table` element. With minor changes, we have the following:

### HTML

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <thead>                
        <tr>
            <th>Apple</th>
            <th>Orange</th>
            <th>Watermelon</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This then allows us to target more specifically the elements we want, i.e. how many columns are there, and what is the "total" cell.

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table thead th').each(function(i)
    {
        calculateColumn(i);
    });
});

function calculateColumn(index)
{
    var total = 0;
    $('table tr').each(function()
    {
        var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
        if (!isNaN(value))
        {
            total += value;
        }
    });

    $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('Total: ' + total);
}​
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#sum_table tr:first td').each(function(){
   var $td = $(this); 

    var colTotal = 0;
    $('#sum_table tr:not(:first,.totalColumn)').each(function(){
        colTotal  += parseInt($(this).children().eq($td.index()).html(),10);
    });

    $('#sum_table tr.totalColumn').children().eq($td.index()).html('Total: ' + colTotal);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/7/

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    for (i=0;i<$('#sum_table tr:eq(0) td').length;i++) {
       var total = 0;
        $('td.rowDataSd:eq(' + i + ')', 'tr').each(function(i) {
           total = total + parseInt($(this).text());
        });            
        $('#sum_table tr:last td').eq(i).text(total);
    }

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/unKDk/10/

Comment: @Greasyque As you are new, it is customary to  mark one of the answers as accepted (clicking the checkmark).  Both you and the person who answers yuor question get points.

Comment: @lucuma and more importantly, others who arrive at this question looking for solutions will find the (subjectively) best answer.

Comment: @jbabey, I agree and I wasn't even implying that he mark my answer only that he mark one of the answers out of the many here that work.

Comment: i wish i could select multiple answer. all of them work great

Answer (score 3):

This is easily accomplished with a little tweaking of the classes on your table:

HTML:

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Watermelon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="total">Total:</td>
        <td class="total">Total:</td>
        <td class="total">Total:</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

JS:

```
var getSum = function (colNumber) {
    var sum = 0;
    var selector = '.col' + colNumber;

    $('#sum_table').find(selector).each(function (index, element) {
        sum += parseInt($(element).text());
    });  

    return sum;        
};

$('#sum_table').find('.total').each(function (index, element) {
    $(this).text('Total: ' + getSum(index + 1)); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/9/

Comment: for some reason i need all the class name to be same instead of different class name

Comment: You can have multiple class names separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been well answered by now, but I started working on this solution earlier before all the answers came through and wanted to go ahead and post it.

This solution works with the HTML as you posted it, and assumes 4 things: 1) the first row is the header row, 2) the last row is the totals row, 3) each row has equal columns, and 4) the columns contain integers. In this case, only the table needs to be identified.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    totalRows("#sum_table");
});

function totalRows(tableSelector) {
    var table = $(tableSelector);
    var rows = table.find("tr");
    var val, totals = [];

    //loop through the rows getting values in the rowDataSd columns
    rows
        .each(function(rIndex) {
            if (rIndex > 0 && rIndex < (rows.length-1)) { //not first or last row
                //loop through the columns
                $(this).find("td").each(function(cIndex) {
                    val = parseInt($(this).html());
                    (totals.length>cIndex) ? totals[cIndex]+=val : totals.push(val);
                });
            }
        })
        .last().find("td").each(function(index) {
            val = (totals.length>index) ? totals[index] : 0;
            $(this).html( "Total: " + val );
        });
}
​
​
```

Comment: great, other way to approach the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go sir! http://jsfiddle.net/47VDK/