# SUM Total for Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

please refer to previous question here: [Sum total for column in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery)

i used Aymen's solution, but i edited it to suite my need. It stopped working, my code as below as seen at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/15/

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
    <tr class="titlerow">
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Watermelon</td>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
        <td>Total By Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowAA">1</td>
        <td class="rowAA">2</td>
        <td class="rowBB">3</td>
        <td class="rowBB">4</td>
        <td class="totalRow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowAA">1</td>
        <td class="rowAA">2</td>
        <td class="rowBB">3</td>
        <td class="rowBB">4</td>
        <td class="totalRow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowAA">1</td>
        <td class="rowAA">5</td>
        <td class="rowBB">3</td>
        <td class="rowBB">4</td>
        <td class="totalRow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery part is

```
var totals=[0,0,0,0,0];
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

    $dataRows.each(function() {
        $(this).find('.rowAA').each(function(i){        
            totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
        });

        $(this).find('.rowBB').each(function(i){        
            totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
        });        
    });
    $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
        $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
    });

});
```

1. how to solve the problem that caused the jquery calculate wrongly.
2. how to calculate total by row
3. i need the class name exactly same.

Comment: An SO question should be fully self-contained and not a follow-up that requires linking to a previous question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum total for column in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery)

Comment: @Redbox If you're looking for a solution that works with any number of rows and column, I've provided one below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want, but if you just want to sum all rows by column then see below..

```
var totalsByRow = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var totalsByCol = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

    $dataRows.each(function(i) {
        $(this).find('td:not(.totalRow)').each(function(j) {
            totalsByCol[j] += parseInt($(this).html());
            totalsByRow[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
        });
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < totalsByCol.length - 1; i++) {
        totalsByCol[totalsByCol.length - 1] += totalsByCol[i];       
    }    

    $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i) {
        $(this).html("total:" + totalsByCol[i]);
    });

    $("#sum_table td.totalRow").each(function(i) {
        $(this).html("total:" + totalsByRow[i]);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/21/)

Comment: sum by column is working now, how about by row? need to sum the same row value and put it to class totalRow

Comment: @Redbox Check the updated post for the total by row and column.

Comment: @Redbox Updated for grand total.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want to target all of the `td` elements that are in the middle rows. Each time you cycle over a new `td`, you want to add its value to both the last td in its row (unless it is the last `td` in the row), and also to the `td` in the last row that shares its index.

```
$("#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)").each(function(c,row) {
  $("td",row).text(function(i,t) {
    var n = parseInt( t, 10 ) || 0;
    $(this).nextAll(":last-child").text(function(a,o) {
      return n + ( parseInt( o, 10 ) || 0 );
    });
    $(row).nextAll("tr:last").find("td:nth-child("+(++i)+")").text(function(a,o){
      return "Total: " + ( n + ( parseInt( o.replace(/[^\d]/g,""), 10 ) || 0 ) );
    });
  });
});
```

​
This should work for any table of any size, not restricting you to x columns, or y rows.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/34/

#### With Commentary

I would encourage you to read the comments in the example below as they will help you understand what is going on with each line.

```
// For each table row that is not first or last
$("#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)").each(function(c,row) {
  // For each td within this row
  $("td",row).text(function(i,t) {
    // Determine numerical value of this td's content
    var n = parseInt( t, 10 ) || 0;
    // Find last td in this row, change its text
    $(this).nextAll(":last-child").text(function(a,o) {
      // Increment its value with the value of current TD
      return n + ( parseInt( o, 10 ) || 0 );
    });
    // Find last row, and td within of same index as current td, change its text
    $(row).nextAll("tr:last").find("td:nth-child("+(++i)+")").text(function(a,o){
      // Increment its value (removing non-numbers) with the value of current td
      return "Total: " + ( n + ( parseInt( o.replace(/[^\d]/g,""), 10 ) || 0 ) );
    });
  // End our td loop
  });
// End our tr loop
});
```