# Calculating column and row sum in html table using jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate the row and column total in an html table. However, I am trying to calculate the row total up to the second to last column. I can do it up to last column but not up to second to last. I also want to remove  Total:0 from the first column. Can you please help me, below is my code:

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <td></td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
            <td>Total By Row</td>
            <td>Strawberry</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Row1</td>
            <td class="rowAA">1</td>
            <td class="rowAA">2</td>
            <td class="rowBB">3</td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
            <td class="rowBB">4</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Row2</td>
            <td class="rowAA">1</td>
            <td class="rowAA">2</td>
            <td class="rowBB">3</td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
            <td class="rowBB">4</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row3</td>
            <td class="rowAA">1</td>
            <td class="rowAA">5</td>
            <td class="rowBB">3</td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
            <td class="rowBB">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)  td:nth-last-child(2)").text(function(){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).prevAll().each(function(){ 
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return t;
});

$("#sum_table tr:last td").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(++i)+")").each(function(){
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return "Total: " + t;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/331/)

I want the table to look like this format :

```
     |Apples|Oranges|Watermelon|TotalRow|Strawberry|
Row1 |
Row2 |
Row3 |
Total|
```

Comment: anyone? i am pulling an all nighter and this is for a project that i have to present today

Comment: possible duplicate of [SUM Total for Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803996/sum-total-for-column)

Comment: i have seen this, nonetheless its a different situation

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to get rid of the "Total: 33" in the bottom-right cell and the "Total: 0" in the bottom-left cell?

Comment: I want to get rid of total:0 but i need total row to be shifted to the left by 1 and strawbery column to be the last column. I dont want stawbery column to be a part of total row. Strawberry column should only have column total

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prevent the bottom-left and bottom-right cells in the table from displaying the total (at least this is how I understand your question), you'll have to change your selector from `#sum_table tr:last td` to `#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)`. And then, to account for the shift in indices (since the `td` element in column 1 has been excluded), you'll have to change `++i` to `i+2`. Here's an updated version of the second part of your JS code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/332/)):

```
$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return "Total: " + t;
});
```

**Edit**: Based on the update you made, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/337/) perhaps more in line with what you're after? This solution basically modifies the HTML code by switching the second-last and last `td`'s in each `tr` (i.e., in each row), and the first CSS selector in the JS code was modified to `#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)  td:nth-child(5)` so that the "Total" gets displayed in the second last column (i.e., the 5th `td` of each applicable row).

If, for whatever reason, you want the HTML code to stay as is and you'd like to implement a purely-JS solution that doesn't involve modifying the HTML code by hand, you can do something like the following ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/338/)):

```
//Swap the second-last and last columns
$("#sum_table tr td:last-child").each(function(){
    var lastRowContent = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
    var secondLastRowContent = $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(5)")[0].innerHTML;
    $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(5)")[0].innerHTML = lastRowContent;
    $(this)[0].innerHTML = secondLastRowContent;
});

$("#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)  td:nth-child(5)").text(function(){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).prevAll().each(function(){ 
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return t;
});

$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first)").text(function(i){
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i+2)+")").each(function(){
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return "Total: " + t;
});
```

This is basically the same as the first solution presented above in this edit, except the second-last and last columns are swapped programmatically using jQuery (instead of being manually swapped by hand).

Comment: no id want to have total row in column 4 and column 5 should be strawberry. I need the results in the row up to column 4 being added together. Column 5 should be added only vertically

Comment: @ivan Check the edit I just made and see if it's more in line with what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/335/

I changed this

```
$("#sum_table tr:last")
```

to

```
$("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)")
```

and

```
$(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(++i)+")").each(function(){
```

to

```
$(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i + 2)+")").each(function(){
```

Comment: no id want to have total row in column 4 and column 5 should be strawberry. I need the results in the row up to column 4 being added together. Column 5 should be added only vertically