# ASP .NET table sum of rows and columns with textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've got an ASP .NET webforms application where employee's are filling out a timesheet. I've got a table that has ASP:TextBox's for user input and what i'd like to do is calculate the sum total of their hours in the current row and the current column.

I've looked at this previous example: [SUM Total for Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803996/sum-total-for-column) and it get's me very close. I run the following javascript on every keyup of any textbox:

```js
var totalsByRow = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var totalsByCol = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sum').keyup(function (e) {
        var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

        $dataRows.each(function (i) {
            $(this).find('td:not(.totalRow)').each(function (j) {
                totalsByCol[j] += parseFloat($(this).val());
                totalsByRow[i] += parseFloat($(this).val());
            });
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < totalsByCol.length - 1; i++) {
            totalsByCol[totalsByCol.length - 1] += totalsByCol[i];
        }

        $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function (i) {
            $(this).html("total:" + totalsByCol[i]);
        });

        $("#sum_table td.totalRow").each(function (i) {
            $(this).html("total:" + totalsByRow[i]);
        });
    });
});
```

The issue is simple: $(this).html() doesn't get the value of the textbox. I've also tried $(this).val() and $(this).value based on other posts with no success. So how do I get the value of the textbox calling this keyup function?

EDIT:

The HTMl code I'm using is just a simple test table i've set up. Here it is for further clarification:

```html
<script src="TotalForm.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table" border="1">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>Strawberry</td>
    <td>Total By Row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rowAA">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowAA">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowBB">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox3" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowBB">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox4" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="totalRow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rowAA">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox5" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowAA">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox6" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowBB">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox7" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowBB">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox8" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="totalRow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rowAA">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox9" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowAA">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox10" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowBB">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox11" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="rowBB">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox12" CssClass="sum"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="totalRow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="totalColumn">
    <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
    <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show as a code snippet from your HTML

Comment: Sure. I just created a very simple table to test out the javascript with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this part of code

```
 $dataRows.each(function (i) {
            $(this).find('td:not(.totalRow)').each(function (j) {
                totalsByCol[j] += parseFloat($(this).val());
                totalsByRow[i] += parseFloat($(this).val());
   });
});
```

by

```
 $dataRows.each(function (i) {
                $(this).find('td:not(.totalRow)').each(function (j) {
                    totalsByCol[j] += parseFloat($(this).find(".sum").val());
                    totalsByRow[i] += parseFloat($(this).find(".sum").val());
       });
    });
```

.fin("sum") to find the input text control.

Comment: try to alert ($(this).find(".sum").val()) in your each statment

Comment: Ahh! So the alert shows the value perfectly it's just that I'm somehow displaying it wrong.

Comment: Using alert(totalsByCol[j]); and alert(totalsByCol[i]); shows that It does take the first number somebody inputs into a text box. Then shortly after everything changes to "NaN"