# How to sum value of every row and column of table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, html-table

```
<table id="repair-invoice">
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Parts</th>
        <th>Labor</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Automatic Transmission Replacement</td>
        <td>$1,809.99</td>
        <td>$830.00</td>
        <td class = 'total-combat'>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Exhaust system replace</td>
        <td class = 'combat'>$279.99</td>
        <td class = 'combat'>$225.00</td>
        <td class = 'total-combat'>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Replace air filter</td>
        <td class = 'combat'>$9.99</td>
        <td class = 'combat'>$0.00</td>
        <td class = 'total-combat'>?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
        <td>?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //iterate through each row in the table
    $('tr').each(function () {
        //the value of sum needs to be reset for each row, so it has to be set inside the row loop
        var sum = 0
        //find the combat elements in the current row and sum it 
        $(this).find('.combat').each(function () {
            var combat = $(this).text();
            if (!isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(combat);
            }
        });
        //set the value of currents rows sum to the total-combat element in the current row
        $('.total-combat', this).html(sum);
    });
});
```

The last column in each item row should contain a total of the parts + labor costs.The final column should contain the total of all the previous rows. If you choose to use jQuery, you can assume that window.$ is available globally. Kindly correct my script. If there is any change required in html , we can do that.

Comment: See [SUM Total for Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803996/sum-total-for-column) and [Sum total for column in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery)

Comment: stackoverflow is not a place to get your work done for free. please do some programming and testing first, and ask specific questions when you got stuck. this is just a job offer right, and there are other platforms for that.

Comment: Assignment ? check the web to "traverse table row using jQuery" hope this helps for the first step.

Comment: I have also written the javascript code. I am not like taking work fro other people. I have written the html and javasript code. kIndly help me out

Answer (score 4):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyy3xutj/17/)

```
var total = 0;

// iterate through rows, exclude first (head) and last (total)
$('#repair-invoice tr').not(':first-child, :last-child').each(function() {
    // parse values and calc. row total
    var rowTotal = parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().substring(1).replace(/,/g, '')) + parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text().substring(1).replace(/,/g, ''));

    total += rowTotal;

    // format value and assign it to last cell
    $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text('$'+ rowTotal.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});

$('#repair-invoice tr:last-child td:last-child').text('$'+ total.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```

Comment: here there is a problem the script you povided that the sum of the first row is not correct. Can you correct that thing, please

Comment: @AnubhavGarg sorry, check it again :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It runs fine

Comment: *You're welcome @AnubhavGarg. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.*

Comment: Likely your code has bug, because sum of `1,809.99` and `830.00` writed `831.00` but i think should be `2,639.99`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update JSFiddle link, now it should work properly.