# Total sum of values from td element (from different classes element)

Tags: jquery, sum

How can I sum 2 different (class elements) total values?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x7QuB/

```
var total_listed=[0,0];
var total_sold=[0,0];
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

    $dataRows.each(function() {
        $(this).find('.DataListed').each(function(i){        
            total_listed[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
        });
        $(this).find('.DataSold').each(function(i){        
            total_sold[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
        });
    });
    $("#sum_table td.totalColListed").each(function(i){  
        $(this).html("$"+total_listed[i]*2);
    });
    $("#sum_table td.totalColSold").each(function(i){  
        $(this).html("$"+total_sold[i]*3);
    });

});
```

In one column under "`.totalColListed`" I have sum of all listed values, and in other td element "`.totalColSold`" I have sum of all sold items.

How to put sum of `.totalColListed+.totalColListed` in new element (td/div/etc) for example div "`.total`" ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `i` in `total_listed[i]` and `total_sold[i]`? You never assign this variable.

Comment: I have just defined var total_listed=[0,0];
var total_sold=[0,0]; (this is from some example I've found here on stackoverflow). What should I do?

Comment: Don't just copy examples without understanding what they're doing. Why do you need arrays instead of single numbers? What does `i` represent in your application?

Comment: I have tried to find here example how to sum all td elements, but I need to sum all total values :/  [i] it's from this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10802805/2391663

Comment: In that example, `i` is the column number, it's the parameter to the `.each()` function. You're not doing a separate total for each column, are you?

Comment: Never mind, I see that you are looping similarly. I didn't see `function(i)`.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and what the expected output should be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x7QuB/  Total = Listed + Sold :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for arrays in your code. The example you copied from was calculating totals for each column, and `i` was the column number. In your code `i` is the row number, so you were just assigning each array element to be the value in that row, you weren't totalling anything (you couldn't see this because one of the rows had 0 for its values, so it didn't affect the total). Here's a version that works.

There's also no need

```
var total_listed = 0;
var listed_mult = 2;
var total_sold = 0;
var sold_mult = 5;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

    $dataRows.each(function () {
        $(this).find('.DataListed').each(function () {
            total_listed += parseInt($(this).html());
        });
        $(this).find('.DataSold').each(function () {
            total_sold += parseInt($(this).html());
        });
    });
    $("#sum_table td.totalColListed").text(total_listed * listed_mult);
    $("#sum_table td.totalColSold").text(total_sold * sold_mult);

    $('.total').text(total_listed*listed_mult + total_sold*sold_mult);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x7QuB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You would just to

```
$('.total').text(
                  parseInt($('.totalColListed').text())+
                  parseInt($('.totalColSold').text()))
                );
```

Comment: You're missing `.html()` or `.text()`.

Comment: Are you successfully filling in `.totalColListed` and `.totalColSold`? The problem with `i` is probably preventing that. You need to get the basic function working before worrying about adding the totals.

Comment: Thank you!!! I have updated: http://jsfiddle.net/x7QuB/1/  it works perfect. You guys must feeling like a God when you know everything :) thank you once again to everyone!