# How to use Javascript to analyze arbitrary html files

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to analyze an html file (I want to find the sum of a column in a table).  I have the code that I think will do this, but I am unsure of how to tell the javascript where to find the html file.

Most of the things I've done with javascript have involved linking the html file to the javascript by including a   tag in the html file.  However, in this case I want to be able to run this analysis on arbitrary html files.  Is there an argument I can pass in to the javascript somewhere?

Edit:  to those asking to see my code, I am using something a lot like the script in the top answer of this stack overflow question: [Sum total for column in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery)

I am trying to make a tool that can be used on various different html files with tables, although all of them should be hosted in the same directory.  It is looking like I would need to use AJAX to do this.  Can the script be run without being attached to an html file?

Edit 2:  I was originally intending to call this javascript from inside a perl script.  However, I am now discovering that Perl might already have some support for analyzing html documents with the HTML::TreeBuilder module.  Depending on how hard it is to use, I might just implement the same function with that in a perl script instead of messing around with javascript.

Comment: Showing your code would be extremely helpful

Comment: Javascript can't read arbitrary files. It can use AJAX to read files from the same domain that the script came from.

Comment: You can write a helper service that will fetch the file for you and make it available over json/jsonp for your script.

Comment: if the html file you need to analyze is not in same domain as your js code, you can not do that with js alone without any serverside script.

Comment: STart with reading what js cannot do: http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/cannot.htm