# How to sum up the values of a table with jquery without adding classes to the table?

Tags: jquery, sum, html-table

I've been trying to write a piece of code to sum up the values of a table in JQuery for weeks and I just don't get it fixed.
My target is to get it without having to modify the source code of the table(i.e. adding classes or IDs to the tds) and also to get something compact. It's the first Thing that I'm coding with JQuery so I guess that it's only a Basic Problem...
I found one function to get the sum of a column which is working well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
           var calculated_total_sum = 0;

           $("table").each(function () {
               var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
               if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
                  calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
                  }                  
                });
                  $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
           });
```

This code is only working for a table with one column. I modified it to make it works for tables with several columns without having to add classes to the source code of the table by using :nth-child() selectors:

```
$("table").on('input', function(){
var calculated_total_sum= 0;
        $("td:nth-child(2) input").each(function(){
            var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
            if($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)){
            calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
            }
    });
   $("tr:last td:nth-child(2) ").html(calculated_total_sum);
   }); 
 });
```

This code works good but has in my case one big issue: the table is pretty big and to implement this code would mean to have to repeat it for each column, so at least 50 times... I guess that there is a better solution to find.

I tried it in two different ways, but none of them works:

1) Create a variable which is getting the index of the selected td and try to insert it in the function:

```
$("td").on('input', function(){
var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
var index= col+1;       
 var calculated_total_sum= 0;
        $("td:nth-child(index) input").each(function(){
            var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
            if($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)){
            calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
            }
    });
   $("tr:last td:nth-child(index) ").html( calculated_total_sum);
    });
```

2) Put the variable directly in the first function:

```
$("td").on('input', function(){
        var calculated_total_sum= 0;
        $("td:nth-child($(this).parent().children().index($(this))) input").each(function(){
            var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
            if($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)){
            calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
            }
    });
   $("tr:last td:nth-child($(this).parent().children().index($(this))) input") ").html( calculated_total_sum);
   });
```

None of both worked and I'm pretty out of idea... I'm a rookie in coding so I guess that I just don't see the little detail which inhibit the function to work. I think it's a selector problem, I searched in a lot of tutorials to find an answer, but I could only find explanations to simple examples which are not covering this type of cases. I'll be really glad if one you could help me!

Got it! I found a function in the answer of another question past week (see the original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery)) which is working pretty good. I only had to adapt it to my case and to change the event to make it work dynamically, the outcome is:

```
    $("input").blur(function() {
    $('table thead th').each(function(i)
    {
        calculateColumn(i);
    });
});

function calculateColumn(index)
{
    var total = 0;
    $('table tr').each(function()
    {
        var value = parseInt($('input', this).eq(index).val());
        if ($.isNumeric(value))
        {
            total += value;
        }
    });

    $('table tfoot td').eq(index).text(total);
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for it